# Multithreading taking equal time as single thread quick sorting

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, pthreads

I'm working on linux but multithreading and single threading both are taking 340ms. Can someone tell me what's wrong with what I'm doing?

Here is my code

```
#include<time.h>
#include<fstream>
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 1000000
using namespace std;

struct parameter
{
        int *data;
        int left;
        int right;
};
void readData(int *data)
{
        fstream iFile("Data.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
                iFile>>data[i];
}

int threadCount = 4;

int Partition(int *data, int left, int right)
{
        int i = left, j = right, temp;
        int pivot = data[(left + right) / 2];
        while(i <= j)
        {
                while(data[i] < pivot)
                        i++;
                while(data[j] > pivot)
                        j--;
                if(i <= j)
                {
                        temp = data[i];
                        data[i] = data[j];
                        data[j] = temp;
                        i++;
                        j--;
                }
        }
        return i;
}

void QuickSort(int *data, int left, int right)
{
        int index = Partition(data, left, right);
        if(left < index - 1)
                QuickSort(data, left, index - 1);
        if(index < right)
                QuickSort(data, index + 1, right);
}

//Multi threading code starts from here
void *Sort(void *param)
{
        parameter *param1 = (parameter *)param;
        QuickSort(param1->data, param1->left, param1->right);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        clock_t start, diff;
        int *data = new int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
        pthread_t threadID, threadID1;
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
        pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
        parameter param, param1;
        readData(data);
        start = clock();
        int index = Partition(data, 0, SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1);
        if(0 < index - 1)
        {
                param.data = data;
                param.left = 0;
                param.right = index - 1;
                pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, Sort, (void *)&param);
        }
        if(index < SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1)
        {
                param1.data = data;
                param1.left = index + 1;
                param1.right = SIZE_OF_ARRAY;
                pthread_create(&threadID1, NULL, Sort, (void *)&param1);
        }
        pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
        pthread_join(threadID, NULL);
        pthread_join(threadID1, NULL);
        diff = clock() - start;
        cout<<"Sorting Time = "<<diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";
        delete []data;
        return 0;
}
//Multithreading Ends here

Single thread main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        clock_t start, diff;
        int *data = new int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
        readData(data);
        start = clock();
        QuickSort(data, 0, SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1);
        diff = clock() - start;
        cout<<"Sorting Time = "<<diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";
        delete []data;
        return 0;
}
//Single thread code ends here
some of functions single thread and multi thread use same
```

Comment: How many CPUs does your computer have?

Comment: Print the `index` variable in the `main` function. If you are extremely unlucky at choosing the pivot in the middle of the array, only one thread will be doing all the work, or the work will be split vary inequally.

Comment: syatem have 24 CPUs and array contains random number.

Comment: Can any body tell if i go with sched_setaffinity by forcing os to assign threads to different CPUs will it reduce the time taken by multi threading sorting

Answer (score 2):

`clock` returns total CPU time, not wall time.

If you have 2 CPUs and 2 threads, then after a second of running both thread simultaneously `clock` will return CPU time of 2 seconds (the sum of CPU times of each thread).

So the result is totally expected. It does not matter how many CPUs you have, the total running time summed over all CPUs will be the same.

Comment: then i should i measure the time taken by the program not from the CPU.

Comment: You can measure wall time with e.g. `gettimeofday`. This will include all periods of inactivity (when CPUs are busy executing other processes), so you better do it on a system which has no extra processes running.

Comment: gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        start = (tv.tv_sec * 1000) + (tv.tv_usec * 0.001);
        QuickSort(data, 0, SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1);
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        diff = start - (tv.tv_sec * 1000) + (tv.tv_usec * 0.001);

Comment: every time i execute the program it give different result with gettimeofday() why??????

Comment: This is normal. There is always small variation in running time according to wall clock, due to variable load on the system and other factors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you call Partition once from the main thread...

The code works on the same memory block which prevents a CPU from working when the other accesses that same memory block. Unless your data is really large you're likely to have many such hits.

Finally, if your algorithm works at memory speed when you run it with one thread, adding more threads doesn't help. I did such tests a while back with image data, and having multiple thread decreased the total speed because the process was so memory intensive that both threads were fighting to access memory... and the result was worse than not having threads at all.

What makes really fast computers today go really is fast is running one very intensive process per computer, not a large number of threads (or processes) on a single computer.

Comment: if i decrese or increse the data size than also single and multi thread take equal time

Comment: And on multi thread some share memory concept is there than how share memory affect thrad allocation on different CPUs

Comment: quicksort doesn't work at the speed of memory, it's dramatically faster.

Comment: i want to know whether os is allocating diff CPU to diff thread or why execution time is same in case of single and multi  thread.

Comment: As unkulunkulu says, the sort goes a lot faster than the memory can sustain. This means adding threads will not help. If you have a really complicated equation that reads a relatively small amount of data do very complex math and then writes the result, the having multiple threads can help. But just swapping two values hits the memory constantly and having multiple threads does not save you anything.

Comment: It means that multithreading sorting is meaning less!!! then how should i reduce the time taken by sorting.

Comment: Design your data so that each thread does not operate on the same data, as far as reasonably practical.  I have had good results with a multithreaded merge sort.  Chop up the data into [L1 cache] size bits, quicksort each then merge. Just design so you can chuck a cacheful of data at each thread - there will be a big speedup, esp. with 24 cores!  Adding threads WILL help - you just have to feed them properly and they will quickly eat up all your data.

Comment: i splitted my data into left and right arrray of equal size and then do quick sort on them. then i merged both arrays but no improvement.

Comment: Is it possible that both the two threads are executing on the single core in round robin fasion. thats why single and multiple taking same time.

Comment: Mayank, no! With 24 cores you sure will get 2 different cores to run your 2 threads. As pointed out by Martin, the sets need to be of a size equal to your L1. If you work on a larger set, then the memory access of one thread prevents the other from running.

Answer (score 1):

Build a thread pool with a producer-consumer queue with 24 threads hanging off it.  Partition your data into two and issue a mergesort task object to the pool, the mergesort object should issue further pairs of mergesorts to the queue and wait on a signal for them to finish and so on until a mergersort object finds that it has [L1 cache-size data].  The object then qicksorts its data and signals completion to its parent task.

If that doesn't turn out to be blindingly quick on 24 cores, I'll stop posting about threads..

..and it will handle multiple sorts in parallel.

..and the pool can be used for other tasks.

.. and there is no No performance-destroying, deadlock-generating join(), synchronize(), (if you except the P-C queue, which only locks for long enough to push an object ref on), no thread-creation overhead and no dodgy thread-stopping/terminating/destroying code.  Like the barbers, there is no waiting - as soon as a thread is finished with a task it can get another.

No thread micro-management, no tuning, (you could create 64 threads now, ready for the next generation of boxes).  You could make the thread count tuneable - just add more threads at runtime, or delete some by queueing up poison-pills.

You don't need a reference to the threads at all - just set 'em off, (pass queue as parameter).

Comment: No need to revert to MergeSort, Just make a task for each "partition" step which returns two new tasks to the pool if they are larger than a given minimum size. To avoid flooding the pool (pun!), after partitioning, push the larger interval onto the pool and continue working on the smaller one.

Comment: @Pedro - there are variations, yes:)  One I'd forgot is that, if an object has to wait on children, it should be stored in one child so that it's not blocking a thread - no hard waiting means no deadlocks.